# How do i get command prompt to recognize certain folders for python script files?

Tags: python, windows, command, prompt

Default python folder: c:/python
My script file name.py is in that folder.
Tested my script in the shell and works. 
When i do python name.py is gives me syntax error in cmd
Now when i changed command prompt start in location to the python folder it worked. Is there a way i dont have to do that but for it to still open if i do python name.py?
Or what do you all recommend?

When i just type python it shows version etc. So i know the variables for that are correct...
So i have no clue

Comment: We are going to need more information.  What commands are you running, what is the exact error code, what is the line of the code that is causing the error

Comment: Don't do this, just write `python the\full\path\name.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to the directory containing your script `C:/python`. See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages).

However, this is not the typical, recommended way to find your Python scripts. It is best to use something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/python')
```